# Price of Enabling Billing Alert

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-billing

I cannot find on the AWS docs the price of [Enabling the Billing Alert](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html#enabling_billing_alerts).
Is it just free? If not, can someone point me to the relevant AWS documentation?

Sorry for this non-technical question. Let me know if I should ask this on another SO page.

Comment: The metrics and alarms are created in CloudWatch, check out its pricing at https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/pricing/

Comment: Gotcha, so if I don't want to create alarms, then just the Cloudwatch metrics would need to be paid?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You can check out the pricing for metrics at the linked page.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear. I'm asking the price of the feature which allows to Enable Billing alert. Doe this enablement incur costs, apart from the cost created from the Cloudwatch metrics?

Comment: It incurs the costs from the created CloudWatch metrics and alarms.

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from [this](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2012/05/10/announcing-aws-billing-alerts/#:%7E:text=Each%20alert%20uses,no%20additional%20charge.) link:

> You can use up to 10 alarms and 1,000 e-mail notifications free each month as part of the AWS Free Tier, and most customers will be able to use billing alerts at no additional charge.

Comment: Yeah I had the same link, but it does not say anything about the price of just enabling the alert? It's just about budget, alarm and sending email.